# Nested resource with Atom Feed Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, feed, atom-feed

I'm trying to use the [Rails Atom Feed Helper](http://github.com/rails/atom_feed_helper/tree/master) to generate a feed for a nested resource.  My view template (index.atom.builder) is:

```
atom_feed(:schema_date => @favourites.first.created_at) do |feed|
  feed.title("Favourites for #{@user.login}")

  feed.updated(@favourites.first.created_at)

  @favourites.each do |favourite|
    feed.entry(favourite, :url => favourite.asset.external_ref) do |entry|
      entry.title(favourite.asset.external_ref)
      entry.content(image_tag(favourite.asset.location), :type => 'html')
      entry.author do |author|
        author.name(@user.login)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I have the following routes:

```
  map.namespace :public do |pub|
    pub.resources :users, :has_many => [ :favourites ]
    pub.resources :favourites
    pub.resources :assets, :only => [ :show ]
  end
```

Unfortunately the url is failing to generate for the feed.entry line:

```
feed.entry(favourite, :url => favourite.asset.external_ref) do |entry|
```

The error is "undefined method `favourite_url' for ActionView::Base".

I've tried changing the feed.entry line to:

```
feed.entry([:public, favourite], :url => favourite.asset.external_ref) do |entry|
```

But this then returns the entry for an Array rather than a favourite!  Someone had a similar problem [here also](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1093-atom-feed-helper-generates-wrong-ids).

I know that adding the line:

```
map.resource :favourites
```

to my routes.rb would 'fix' this problem but this resource is only available nested beneath the /public namespace.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Cheers
Arfon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `favourite.asset.external_ref` as the title of the entry, which leaves me to believe the URL for that entry should probably be defined as:

```
public_user_favourite_url(:id => favourite, :user_id => @user)
```

Which, if `favorite.id = 9` and `@user.id = 1`, would generate:

```
http://localhost:3000/public/users/1/favourites/9
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hey thanks, that worked!  I'm not sure how I missed that option :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up.  Based upon Michael's suggestion I'm passing the full url param and this seems to generate the correct url for the feed.entry line.

```
  @favourites.each do |favourite|
    feed.entry(favourite, :url => public_user_favourite_url(:id => favourite, :user_id => @user)) do |entry|
      entry.title(favourite.asset.external_ref)
      entry.content(image_tag(favourite.asset.location), :type => 'html')
      entry.author do |author|
        author.name(@user.zooniverse_user_id)
      end
    end
  end
```