# url in atom feed-builder behaves different to erb-template with nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have the following nested resource:

```
resources :categories, :only => [:show], :path => "" do
resources :games, :only => [:show], :path => "" do
end
```

To retrieve all items i do:

```
 @feeditems = Game.all(:include => [:categorygames => :category])
```

To show them in an .erb template:

```
<%= category_game_path(feeditem.categorygames.first.category, feeditem) %>
```

This works fine so far. Now i wanted to use the same way to include the url in a 
atom feed. I have to specify the url, so i did the following:

```
@feeditems.each do |feeditem|
feed.entry(feeditem, :url => category_game_path(feeditem.categorygames.first.category, feeditem)) do |entry|
  entry.title feeditem.name_de
...
```

Unfortunately i always get a "NoMethodError"-Error, and "undefined method `category_game__path' #<#:0x007fa7c96c3090>"

Why does builder behaves different to a .erb-template? Any idea, how can sort this out?

**EDIT**

I got one step further, since [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198484/nested-resource-with-atom-feed-helper?rq=1) had a similar problem.

I changed it to this:

```
 feed.entry(:url => url_for(:action => 'show', :controller =>'games', :category_id => feeditem.categorygames.first.category, :id => feeditem, :only_path => false)) do |entry|
```

Now i get this error:

```
     undefined method `id' for {:url=>"http://localhost:3000/sport-games/wizard-game"}:Hash
```

Still, i do not have an idea so solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but after restarting the server and a cold reload, it works this way:

```
feed.entry(feeditem, :url => url_for(:action =>'show', :controller =>'games',:category_id => feeditem.categorygames.first.category, :id => feeditem, :only_path => false)) do |entry|
```